# Active Record Relationship - uninitialized constant User

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Below code works on Rails-2 application but its not work in Rails-3 upgrade:

**In user.rb model:**

```
has_many :auction_lots, :class_name => "Auction::Lot", :order => "position"
```

**In lot.rb model:**

```
class Auction::Lot < ActiveRecord::Base
   include ActionController::UrlWriter
   belongs_to :user
   scope :unplanned, :conditions => "status < #{STATUS[:in_stock]}"
end
```

ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant User::AuctionLot):

```
150:     <% unless current_user.auction_lots.unplanned.empty? %>

activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `compute_type'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:117:in `klass'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:86:in `method_missing'
```

Please explain anyone. What is the problem between rails-2 and rails-3

Comment: Are you sure that you have specified `:class_name => "Auction::Lot"` in your `User` model? The error you report is exactly what you would see if Rails was trying to figure out the association class name "automagically".

Comment: Urlwriter is not included as per Rails-3.Its correct way to incude "include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers"..It works for me...Thanks for all contributions...

Answer (score 0):

Urlwriter is not included as per Rails-3.

Its correct way to incude "include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers".

It works for me.